# protobuf schema convert to ORC schema

Tags: protocol-buffers, orc

I wonder if there exists any implementation that can convert protobuf schema into ORC schema.

For example, given a protobuf Message definition `People`:

```
message People {
   string name = 1;
   uint32 age = 2;
}
```

It returns the ORC schema like `struct<name:string,age:int>`.

Comment: Were you able to find a good solution to this?

Comment: @DanHill I end up implementing it myself. Similar to https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/master/java/tools/src/java/org/apache/orc/tools/json/JsonSchemaFinder.java